# Switch class on reaching same Alphabet block while scrolling down or up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with horizontal list of all alphabets and below it there are block of names starting with each alphabet and header of each block is same alphabet.

So I want to add a class in div containing alphabet which is child of div with horizontal list .

You can see [sample link](http://www.artspace.com/artists/). On scrolling down you'll see Alphabet block which we are currently in will have pink colored selection on top horizontal bar.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap Scroll Spy
Look at the answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134013/how-to-use-bootstrap-scroll-spy

Comment: I think this question is essentially dependent on a link to the website in progress, and as such does not contain the necessary elements in the question itself. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to compare the window scroll position with each of the 'sections' on the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        var sp = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('div[data-letter]').each(function(){
            if(sp > $(this).offset().top-40){
                $('#nav span').removeClass('active');
                $('#nav span[data-letter="'+$(this).attr('data-letter')+'"]').addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This can be (massively) improved, but this should you a good starting point.
I'd have spent a bit more time on it if you'd have created a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing us what you'd already tried!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/CmZ8G/)