# Cannot properly refresh Bootstrap scrollspy spying on <body> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134013/how-to-use-bootstrap-scroll-spy) post regarding Bootstrap's scrollspy component. In my code, I instantiate a new scrollspy to spy on the `body` element using:

```
$("body").scrollspy({ offset: 25 });
```

Later on in my code, I make an AJAX call and add/remove elements from the page. This causes the scrollspy to be misaligned, so I need to refresh the scrollspy. I have tried performing this refresh operation many ways, such as:

```
$("body").scrollspy("refresh");
```

and

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
});
```

However, neither of these code snippets bring about any change in the behavior of the scrollspy. I believe this is because the scrollspy is spying directly on the `body` element, but I am unsure of how to have the scrollspy refresh following my AJAX calls. Does anyone know how I might refresh my scrollspy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that it is not possible to refresh a scrollspy that is set to spy on the `body` element via a call to `$("body").scrollspy()`. In order to use the refresh functionality documented on the Bootstrap website, I had to explicitly declare the `data-spy` and `data-target` attributes of the `body` tag (where `scrollingNav` is the `id` of the `nav` bar in which to visualize the scrolling):

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#scrollingNav">
```

Then, to refresh this scrollspy when elements were dynamically added/removed from the page, I used the following method:

```
function refreshScrollSpy() {
    $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
        $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
    }); 
};
```

Comment: very useful finding! I've been breaking my head for several hours.